# CSS Text-Transform:Capitalize Oddity

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have a [page that shows a javascript countdown](http://www.flcbranson.org/elegant.php).  The javascript automatically populates "d" for days, "h" for hours, etc...  CSS adds "ay(s)", "our(s)", etc..., as space allows, and capitalizes them.

Javascript:

```
function cdtd(broadcast) {
    var nextbroadcast = new Date(broadcast);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = nextbroadcast.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<a href=\"flconlineservices.php\">Internet broadcast in progress<\/a>";
        /* Run any code needed for countdown completion here */
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = days + " d";
    document.getElementById("hoursBox").innerHTML = hours + " h";
    document.getElementById("minsBox").innerHTML = minutes + " m";
    // seconds isn't in our html code (javascript error if this isn't commented out)
    /*document.getElementById("secsBox").innerHTML = seconds + " s";*/
    var timer = setTimeout('cdtd(broadcast)',1000);
}
```

CSS:

```
[role="navigation"] {text-transform:capitalize;}
@media screen and (min-width:1600px) {
    #countdown #daysBox:after {content:"ay(s)";}
    #countdown #hoursBox:after {content:"our(s)";}
    #countdown #minsBox:after {content:"inute(s)";}
}
```

Firefox and Opera display the countdown as I expected (3 Day(s), 5 Hour(s), etc...), but Internet Explorer capitalizes the (s) (3 Day(S), 5 Hour(S), etc...).  Safari and Chrome are even worse, as they capitalize the (s) and the first letter of the CSS generated content (3 DAy(S), 5 HOur(S), etc...).

I found a [page that shows typography bugs with :first-letter and :first-line](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-typography-experiment/demo/bugs.html) that may be somewhat related.

I tried doing `text-transform:lowercase` and then `text-transform:capitalize`, but that didn't change the results.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I'll probably just knock out the capitalization, but then I have to make sure everything is typed in the correct casing.

JJ

Comment: I'm using Chrome/Ubuntu and I can't reproduce your problem neither in a fiddle or in your site. But you have this on your site in your script : `days + " D";` (yes, with a uppercase D).

Comment: Also can't repro in IE9 or Chrome (Win7). Also check these out: http://www.jquery4u.com/image-scripts/10-awesome-jquery-count-scripts/

Comment: @dystroy Hehehe...Maybe I shouldn't have fixed it.  I'll set it back to the way it was.

Comment: @lazfish I try to not use jquery.  I do so little javascript that it seems a waste to load things like that for something that only requires a few lines.  I'll keep those in mind, though.

Comment: It may be worth noting that I'm running Windows 7.  It's possible that other operating systems produce different results.

Comment: Yeah they are pretty. I'm on W7 what v of IE did you see this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so from what I can tell you just need the first letter of days, hours and minutes caps. You can do this in javascript. Something like

```
var daysString = days + " d";
document.getElementById("daysBox").innerHTML = daysString.toUpperCase();
```

Update: forgot to mention take our #countdown {text-transform:capitalize;}

Comment: That didn't work.  The problem isn't the javascript string but the css-generated content after the string.

Comment: @doubleJ you need to take out #countdown {text-transform:capitalize;}
 from what I can see, you just want the first letter capitalized. My solution is to do it in the js and leave the css out since it is behaving inconsistently across browsers. Forgot to mention it in my answer

Comment: Wow...I just realized that I created a problem by trying to adjust the code for brevity.  It's actually `[role="navigation"] {text-transform:capitalize;}` but I changed it to `#countdown` as it didn't make sense without the accompanying HTML code.  I want all of the navigation items to be capitalized.  The final outcome was that I simply added `#countdown {text-transform:none;}` and did D, H, M, S in javascript.